# TestFX How to understand the color of an item?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-3d, testfx

I am trying to get a rectangle's background color. I tried to find a way but i couldnt. Isnt there a method makes all this easy? Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
    Rectangle rectangle = lookup("#rectangleId").queryAll().iterator().next();
    Paint color = rect.getFill();
    assertThat(color,is(color2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
List<Node> chieldNode = new ArrayList<>();
    chieldNode = ParentNode.getChildren();
    if (chieldNode.size() != 0) {
        for (Node node : chieldNode) {
            if (node instanceof Rectangle ) {
                Paint color = ((Rectangle ) node).getFill();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how can you reach to rectangle which is defined in applicaton's class not in test's class.

Comment: Replace parentNode  to your application root node,here rectangle  is a child node of parent node